# display previously created view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would normally use a segue to switch view controllers, but I don't think I can use a segue for what I'm doing. I have an alert that appears when the game ends that tells the user that the game is over. There are two buttons that the user can tap on the alert view. One is "try again" and the other is "main menu". When the user taps "main menu" it switches to the main view controller. However when I use "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" it creates a new instance of that main view controller each time the user taps "main menu". How do I have the "main menu" button in the alert view switch to the original instance of the main view controller? Here's my code:

```
gameOverAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Main Menu", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        self.ReturnToMainMenu()
    }))

func ReturnToMainMenu(){
    var storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let Main = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main") as! ViewController

    self.presentViewController(Main, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dismiss your presented view controller (your game), so that it shows your previous view controller (your main menu).

In your return to main menu, `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)`

Comment: Genius. why didn't I think of this? Thank you so much!